# jquery tokeninput in menu list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-tokeninput

I am facing a problem while using token input in my menu list. 
on hover of menu list my sublist opens and in that when i search for tokens input box and after result i wanted to select one token but the window is being closed .. please help

```
 <ul id="navlist">
   <li>list one
     <ul id="subnavlist">
        <li> <input type="text" id = "test" name= "test1" size='6'></test1>
        </li></ul>
      </li></ul>
```

my css goes like this

```
  ul#navlist li:hover
 {
background-color: #ffffff;
border:1px solid #E46713;
 padding-bottom:10px;
```

}

```
ul#subnavlist { display: none; }
ul#subnavlist li { float: left; }


ul#navlist li:hover ul#subnavlist
{
display: block;
position: absolute;
font-size: 8pt;
padding-top: 0px;
width:auto;
}

 ul#navlist li:hover ul#subnavlist li 
{
 display: block;
 border: 2px;
 padding: 0px;
 }
```

Comment: Can you please create a jsfiddle, so we can see more clearly what your problem is, and experiment with how to solve it?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/QhGga/       this is my jsfiddle link you can see more clearly in this. when ever i try to select from auto suggest the list is being closed.

Comment: Blegh, that's a nasty CSS problem! I'm not a CSS genius, but don't think there would be a pure CSS solution. I'd write some javascript so that on hover of the class `token-input-focused` (Not sure on the precise name, check that!) - the CSS above that makes your sublist `display:block` is also applied.

Comment: No solution here, just an explanation. Basically token-input-dropdown is absolutely positioned and removed from the normal flow thus unaffected by the ```li:hover```